# Sequel Pro - Socket connection failed

Tags: mamp, sequelpro

I use Sequel Pro and MAMP on my Mac to develop wordpress sites locally. This morning when I tried to start up Sequel Pro it kept asking for my password to make changes (it has never done this before). I first tried rebooting my machine but it kept asking so I entered my password to allow (unknown) changes to be made.

Big mistake!

Now when I try to connect via socket I get the error message

> Socket connection failed!
>
> Unable to connect via the socket, or the request timed out.
>
> Double-check that the socket path is correct and that you have the necessary privileges, and that the server is running.
>
> MySQL said: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)

When I check MAMP the Apache Server light is red, and the MySQL server light is green.

I am a complete novice when it comes to back-end stuff like this, a lot of the answers I have browsed list console commands but I have never used the console before.

I have found a file that is reference in the error - "mysql.sock". This is located in Applications > MAMP > tmp > mysql > mysql.sock

But im not sure what to do with this file (if anything!).

I also found this error log:

> 130312 11:07:29 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /Applications/MAMP/db/mysql
> 130312 11:07:29 [Warning] You have forced lower_case_table_names to 0 through a command-line option, even though your file system '/Applications/MAMP/db/mysql/' is case insensitive.  This means > that you can corrupt a MyISAM table by accessing it with different cases. You should consider changing lower_case_table_names to 1 or 2
> 130312 11:07:29 [Warning] One can only use the --user switch if running as root
>
> 130312 11:07:29 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
> 130312 11:07:29 [Note] Plugin 'ndbcluster' is disabled.
> 130312 11:07:29  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 0 15469736
> 130312 11:07:30 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
> 130312 11:07:30 [Note] /Applications/MAMP/Library/libexec/mysqld: ready for connections.
> Version: '5.1.37'  socket: '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 8889  Source distribution
> 130312 11:09:37 mysqld_safe A mysqld process already exists

I just dont know what to do with any of the info! Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem just go and `on` or `start` your `MAMP` and then `connect`
via `socket` in `Sequel Pro` it will work.